# Cut certain range in a row and insert below the same row

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel raw data.

```
        A   B   C   D   E   F
   1.   A1  B1  C1      E1  F1
   2.   A2  B2  C2      E2  F2
   3.   A3  B3  C3      E3  F3
   4.   A4  B4  C4      E4  F4
```

I want to cut E1 and F1 then insert it below the same line.

The output should be as per below.

```
        A   B   C   D   E   F
   1.   A1  B1  C1      
   2.   E1  F1
   3.   A2  B2  C2
   4.   E2  F2  
   5.   A3  B3  C3
   6.   E3  F3
   7.   A4  B4  C4
   8.   E4  F4
```

Comment: You're asking us how you are going to do it? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer after a few days later of trial and error. Hopefully it can help others. Thank you.

```
Sub Test()
For i = 2 To 1000


   If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
   Exit For
   End If

    For j = 7 To 1000 Step 4


        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
            Else
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(i, j).Resize(, 8).Cut
            i = i + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Range("A" & i).Insert xlShiftDown
            End If

            Next

       Next

End Sub
```